C# ASP.NET Webforms image uploading
I am trying to do something for my job but everything I am doing is not helping. Even asked ChatGPT and it cannot help.
I am trying with C# / ASP.NET Webforms to use a FileUploadControl to upload multiple images, up to 4 at a time, and save each image to a directory using Server.MapPath.
If I upload one image, it works fine. If I do a Ctrl-A to select all 4 images, it uploads fine. But if I select each image one by one, it only uploads one image.
Any suggestions on how to get around this? Thanks all.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Quite much how the fileupload works.  If you select one file  and then use select again   then the last file is the one file.  This allows users to change their mind. So you have ONLY ONE select chance.  You can select multiple files,  but each time you use select,  it will overwrite existing selects. Fileupload has worked this way for over 20 years. This is perfectly normal behavior

Coming to your question, I have doubt about which .NET framework you are using. Anyways, I will assume you are using .NET 2.0 or above


 
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileuplaod1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" />  
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload Files" OnClick="btnUpload_Click"/>

 protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string msg=string.Empty;
     string msg1 = string.Empty;
     try
     {
         // Check File Prasent or not  
         if (fileuplaod1.HasFiles)
         {`enter code here`
             int fcount = 0;
             int fileuploadcount = 0;
             //check No of Files Selected  
             fcount = fileuplaod1.PostedFiles.Count();
             if (fcount <= 4)
             {
                 foreach (HttpPostedFile postfiles in fileuplaod1.PostedFiles)
                 {
                     //Get The File Extension  
                     string filetype = Path.GetExtension(postfiles.FileName);
                     //you can use multiple checks here or ignore this if statement
                     if (filetype.ToLower() == ".doc")
                     {
                         //Get The File Size In Bite  
                         double filesize = postfiles.ContentLength;
                         if (filesize < (1048576))
                         {
                             fileuploadcount++;
                             string serverfolder = string.Empty;
                             string serverpath = string.Empty;
                             // Adding File Into Scecific Folder Depend On his Extension                                      
                                     serverfolder = Server.MapPath(@"uplaodfiles\document\");
                                     //check Folder avlalible or not  
                                     if (!Directory.Exists(serverfolder))
                                     {
                                         // create Folder  
                                         Directory.CreateDirectory(serverfolder);
                                     }
                                     serverpath = serverfolder + Path.GetFileName(postfiles.FileName);
                                     fileuplaod1.SaveAs(serverpath);
                                     label1.Text += "[" + postfiles.FileName + "]- document file uploaded  successfully<br/>";
                             
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             msg += "[" + postfiles.FileName + "]- files not uploded size is greater then(x)MB.<br/>Your File Size is(" + (filesize / (1024 * 1034)) + ") MB </br>";
                         }
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         msg += "[" + postfiles.FileName + "]- file type must be .doc or pdf and other<br/>";
                     }
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 
                msg += "please select Maximum five(10) files !!!";
             }
             
             msg = "ToTal File =(" + fcount + ")<br/> Uploded file =(" + fileuploadcount + ")<br/> Not Uploaded=(" + (fcount - fileuploadcount) + ")";
         }
         else
         {
         
            msg1 = "<b>please choose the file for upload !!!</b></br>";
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         throw ex;
     }
 }


Thank you, but I am getting the same issue.

See my comment- fileupload allows ONLY ONE file select use. You are free to select multiple files,  but each time you click on fileupload   it will overwrite the previous selected files. This allows users to change selected files.  So while you can select multiple files , you can only do so by selecting multiple files- you can't use fileupload button to cumulative add files - one selecting of files is only allowed- fileupload has worked this way for over 20 years.

yes I did thank, thanks, but does not work
